# Jquery: Could not send to window: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this peice of code such as:

```
function image() {
    var debug = true;
    try{
        var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top;
        win.send_to_editor('[button size="" color="" link=""]place title here[/button]');
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Could not send to window: " + e);
    }

}
```

That when Used will send some text from the popup window to my editor, my wysiwyg. How ever it keeps throwing the error:

**Could not send to window: Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: [button size="" color="" link=""]place title here[/button]**

this should just be sent to the editor, any ideas?

Comment: What's inside `send_to_editor`? That's where the problem is, your `try` is just hiding the stack trace. Take it out.

Comment: How is send_to_editor defined() defined?

Comment: when this question is related to wordpress: Which wordpress-version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `[` to `<` and `]` to `>`. Or, if you do need square brackets, wrap it with some tags like `span`. e.g. `<span>[button size="" color="" link=""]place title here[/button]</span>`.

Since OP haven't shown the source of function `send_to_editor`, I can just guess that
`win.send_to_editor` will probably call something like `jQuery('img',html)`, where `html` is the string he passed in. It should be a valid HTML fragment, because jQuery will parse it on the fly and return the elements in that context. Otherwise, it may cause parse error (e.g. `Sizzle.error`).

**Update**
As per OP's request, here is a simple example:

`jQuery("img","<div id='whatever'><img url='a.png'/></div>").attr('url')` will return string `a.png`.  Here jQuery parses the second argument as a HTML fragment, retrieves the img part and eventually returns its url.

Comment: do you have any examples of this? I think I follow, how ever a example would be best

Comment: As other commenters said, you should specify where `send_to_editor` is from. It's neither native JavaScript function nor jQuery function.

Comment: I guess it's this one: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-admin/js/media-upload.js.source.html#l5

Comment: @KyleAdams I added an example in my answer.

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for, looking at the example. I wanted to send the "[button size="" color="" link=""]place title here[/button]" to the editor. not get a specific part of it.

Comment: I just pointed out how the error could happen. Could you give us the source of the function `send_to_editor`?

Comment: @KyleAdams Anyway, I updated my answer again, hoping it works.